# What is a good replacement for Click & Grow "Smart Soil"?

Tags: vegetables, indoors, soil, herbs

I was given the 9-pod click & grow (https://www.clickandgrow.com/) as a gift, shipped to Australia. Somehow it made it past customs and I've started the growth cycle for the starter pack of seeds, so far so good!

We have very strict agricultural product regulations and as such, any soil product isn't able to be shipped here; so I have been trying to find a replacement for the click & grow smart soil. I have come across the Root Riot (https://www.hydrodynamicsintl.com/product/root-riot-cubes-bags/) as a potential replacement but I'm not sure if it will support the plant throughout the whole growth cycle.

It needs enough nutrients to bring herbs and small vegetables to harvest within the plastic pods.

Comment: My wife has one of these. You can really use any soil, even inert ceramic beads if you wanted to.  Just use a fertilizer for hydroponics which include all micro nutrients.

Answer (score 1):

You got lucky with Biosecurity, big fines available...

Looks like the soil may be mostly cocopeat. Used because it holds a lot of water, and lets air through as well. You can buy a brick of it at Bunnings and soak in a bucket. Lots of options for fertiliser, the pods probably have hydroponic nutrient mix added.

If you or your friends still have the little Discovery Garden boxes from Woolworths, you can use the compressed button in your click-and-grow, with some extra potting mix or cocopeat.

Comment: Are you in Victoria?

Answer (score 0):

This little garden thingy is very temporary.  Looks great to do for short stuff like radish, watercress but plants that grow larger will not get enough light to make their own food with which to use for growth and reproductive grow. Squash would not be good for example.  The leaves are not able to get enough light.

Perhaps if you were trying to grow stuff out on your patio?  Covered patio?  This would work. The only soil that should be used for any and all potted plants is plain sterilized potting medium.

Definitely get the cheap plain jane sterilized potting medium.  Make sure you don't get fertilizer added or water holding gimmicks such a sponges and gels.

Note:  Just went through your second link.  This looks like great stuff to clone plants.  Proper directions as far as I could see. And you are correct, this will NOT support the plant any farther than two leaf sets.

Once you see roots coming out of the cube, transplant that cube and plant into a 6" pot using plain plain sterilized potting medium. Medium should be 1 inch below rim for watering. Hole in bottom of pot.  No rocks or gravel below soil.  Raise the pot off surface using 1/4 inch pieces of tile. Feel the heft of the pot/soil/plant when watered fully.  Do not water again until that pot/soil/plant when lifted again feels OBVIOUSLY lighter.

Use a tiny bit of fertilizer and I recommend for newbies (and myself) Osmocote 14-14-14 all purpose, extended release fertilizer.  Use half of what the directions recommend.

Make sure you have ventilation meaning moving air all around your plant and plants.  Water during the day, not at night. If you are indoors or a green house you have to use the proper lighting at the proper height, maintain the heat 55 - 70 F., keep humidity stable and use a fan that blows YOUR hair around for ventilation.

To replace the soil, simply use sterilized plain jane potting medium!

Comment: I think the goal for the Click & Grow unit is to provide some small edibles grown completely indoors on artificial light. Each pod lasts approximately 2-3 months before you can either replant into proper potting medium or replace with a new pod. Sort of like a Nespresso system for herbs and small veges.

So ideally, I'm looking for some way to replicate this with whatever is available in Australia.

Comment: I get it.  I hope I wasn't putting this gizmo down...just pointing out deal breakers.  Such as that light is only good for tiny edibles.  To replace the soil use sterilized potting medium.  There should be no other input on your part other than a bit of fertilizer and proper water.  Are you wanting to replicate the soil or the entire shebang?

Comment: A major part of the requirements is to use the water from the tank below via the water transfer wicks. I've tested successfully with Jiffy peat pellets with controlled release plant food pellets stuffed into it.
The system has enough pods to give me a constant fresh supply of herbs if I cycle it properly!

Comment: Their secret to getting it past customs would be sterilization certification.  You could have a steady supply of herbs grown in potting soil in small pots on the window sill (south facing)?